# MySQL column to show the sum of column in another table

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, sql-update

I have two tables in SQL both hold the ID of users.

Table Accounts

```
ID    username     Points
1       abc          ? 
2       def          ?
```

Table Transactions

```
ID    Points
1       10
1       -5
2       20
```

The table accounts column points should have the sum of that ID in table transactions. So in table one, the output should be points of ID 1 to be 5 and id 2 to be 20.

I am new to MySQL so if you could just explain the query a bit will be appreatiated.

Comment: Have you tried some query already? If you are absolutely clueless, please read about "inner join", "Group by" , "sum"

Comment: I have tried anything. Im clueless

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an `UPDATE` statement:

```
UPDATE Accounts a
SET a.Points = (SELECT SUM(t.Points) FROM Transactions t WHERE t.ID = a.ID)
```

The correlated subquery returns the sum of points of each `ID`.

Comment: Is there a way to make this query be the value of that column always? I mean, I have to run this query to update the values each time right?

Comment: @Derik002 if this is not a school assignment then you should not do it at all. Storing this type of of values is always a bad idea. The column `Points` in the table `Accounts` should not even be there. If you want to get the sum of points of each id then you should get it in a SELECT query by joining the tables. Check this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0d32e4124222342677cedabbe78383cf

Comment: Actually, it is not a school assignment. Thanks for the tip I will keep it separated from the main db

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's a proper design for your data. Since you can obtain the value for the column `Point` whenever you want from a table, and why do you need to multiplex it, and will need more maintenance for every update to keep the veracity of the data ? Rather create a view containg an outer join such as

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW v_acc_trs AS
SELECT a.ID, a.username, SUM(t.Points) total_points 
  FROM Accounts a 
  LEFT JOIN Transactions t
    ON t.ID = a.ID
 GROUP BY a.ID, a.username
```

and use it whenever to selected the data with the desired criteria :

```
SELECT * FROM v_acc_trs WHERE ...
```